# PowerShell - How does a cmdlet return value?

Tags: powershell

Please consider the following PowerShell assignment statement:

```
$rc = (gci -r -fi *.rar)
```

If there is a rar file present in the directory structure, then `echo $?` displays the following:

```
    Directory: C:\file tests

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         7/22/2012   7:09 PM    3699776 somefile.rar
```

Fine.  Now consider this PowerShell if statement:

```
if (gci -r -fi *.rar)
{
    echo "Rar files found"
}
else 
{
    echo "No rar files"
}
```

In the if statement, the return from the gci cmdlet is treated as a boolean value.  But the return from the same cmdlet produced a string output in case of the earlier assignment statement.

I know that PS is an object shell.  I understand cmdlets act differently depending on context.  But what I don't understand is how this is accomplished, and what mechanisms are used.

**Specifically:** What is the magic used by the *if* statement that allows the return from gci to be treated as a boolean?  If I wanted to use that mechanism elsewhere (outside of an if statement), what would I have to do?  Is there some sort of a "cast to boolean" operator?  E.g.

```
$rc = (Cast following to boolean)(gci -r -fi *.rar)
```

Comment: it's not returning boolean but is returning that it is either $null or not $null

Comment: ie. `$(gci -r -fi *.rar) -eq $null`

Comment: @jbockle: Upped your comments, thank you.  What does the `$(...)` surrounding the `gci -r -fi *.rar` do?  I have tried it without the dollar sign, and it still works.  I.e. `(gci -r -fi *.rar) -eq $null`

Comment: It is just variable expansion however I add $ just out of habit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This table gives you the answer.

```
True                                         False
~~~~                                         ~~~~~
$TRUE                                        $FALSE
Any string of length > 0                     Empty string
Any number ≠ 0                               Any number = 0
Array of length > 1                          Array of length 0
Array of length 1 whose element is true      Array of length 1 whose element is false
A reference to any object  <<<<<             $NULL
```

Idea behind this is to use similar checks to verify if an object is initialized properly.

Comment: +1 Thanks.  So, if I understand correctly, the reason the `if` statement returns true when there is a rar file is because of the string that is returned (i.e. "Directory: C:\file tests...").  Do I understand correctly?

Comment: gci can either return null or FileSystemInfo or Array of FileSystemInfo. So it depends on your folder content. If have only one file it will be true due to 'A reference to any object' rule. If you get an array it will be true due to Array of length >  rule. If you get null it will be false due to Null rule.

Comment: Thank you, very concise answer.

Comment: Not sure I agree about the string "false".`if('false'){'false is true!'}`

Comment: @MikeShepard Don't confuse the english language with the powershell language. How should such a script run on a French locale? Should it do the same for "vrai" ? There are no keywords in strings, just strings.

Comment: @Sabuncu - there are no strings returned from gci/dir. You only see that when the objects are not captured (in a variable or piped to a cmdlet) and end up being sent as output to the formatter for visual consumption.

Comment: My comment was related to the second item in the "false" column in the answer, stating that the empty string or the string "false" are considered false.  I don't agree that this is the case, and the short bit of code I included shows that it is not.

Comment: @x0n OK, so what causes `gci -r -fi *.rar` to have a "true" value is the fact that a single object was returned (corresponding to 'somefile.rar').  Is this correct?  Even so, I still don't understand how the conditional in the if statement can interpret an object as a "true" value.  Is this a mechanism that's built into PowerShell?

Comment: @MikeShepard Sorry, you're right - I have no idea where he got that table from. I just edited it to remove this nonesense. I couldn't quite see it before due to the scrollbars.  :D

Comment: @Sabuncu Yes. Anything that's not null, not 0, not $false and not an empty collection is considered $true. This is very useful generally speaking and is not just a powershell thing. Javascript has this concept of "truthiness" too.

Comment: Should unsafe practices warrant adding to the table above? That is, (though I would of course not advise it) if you run without `Set-PSDebug -strict` you can test an undefined variable, as in `if (!$abc) { ... }`. PowerShell treats that identically to defining the variable as null, to wit `$abc = $null; if (!$abc) { ... }`.

Comment: Great table @Klark !  Do you have a link of references?

Answer (score 1):

I think Powershell just treats null and zero as false like so:

```
PS > if(1) {"True"} else {"False"}
True
PS > if(0) {"True"} else {"False"}
False
PS > if($null) {"True"} else {"False"}
False
```

To cast use the following format:

```
PS > [Bool]"1"
True
```

Comment: +1 Thanks.  Also, casting null string to bool yields False; i.e. `[Bool]""` is false.